# Execute selenium click with ID based on different classes in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have two selenium elements where i need to click. But these elements are with a different id.

```
findElement(By.id(ID_1)).click();

findElement(By.id(ID_2)).click();
```

findElement(By.id(ID_1)).click() should be clicked if the Class_1 is executed, if Class_2 is called, then findElement(By.id(ID_2)).click() should be clicked.

I am trying to avoid duplicate code because these above 2 find elements are inside one method which is called Class_1 and Class_2.

I tried something like this but it didn't solve my issue

```
  if (Class_1.class)
        {
            findElement(By.id(ID_1)).click();
        }
    
  else if (Class_2.class)
        {
            findElement(By.id(ID_2)).click();
        }
```

I am getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Class_1> to boolean".  I mean I am trying to do like this. If this is class_1, then run this, else run else if part.

Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Comment: I did not get it, why do you want to differentiate based on class ? why not in a single class ?

Comment: @cruisepandey because these two classes refers to different IPs addresses to perform some tasks. and both classes access to this method. If i create two methods, then issue is solved but code will be duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You schouldn't separate your test into two (or more) different classes.
Instead use one class and parametrize your method:

```
public void myTestMethod(String ipAdress) {
    if (ipAdress.equals("FOO_IP")) {
        findElement(By.id("FOO_ID")).click();
    }
    else if (ipAdress.equals("BAR_IP")) {
        findElement(By.id("BAR_ID")).click();
    }
    else {
        // code for uknown ip adress
    }
}
```

and simply call the method with desired argument:

```
myTestMethod("FOO_IP");
myTestMethod("BAR_IP");
```